# parameters for LsaICryptUnprotectData

Tags: c++

I am trying to call LsaICryptUnprotectData but I get error code 87 unsupported parameter. Has anyone been able to successfully call this function?  would like to see an example function call

Here is how I am calling,

```
typedef int (WINAPI *LPFUN_LSAICRYPTUNPROTECTDATA) 
(
    LPBYTE encCredData,
    DWORD encCredDataSize,
    DWORD reserved1,
    DWORD reserved2,
    DWORD reserved3,
    DWORD reserved4,
    DWORD dwFlags,
    DWORD reserved5,
    LPBYTE *decCredData,
    LPDWORD decCredDataSize
);

 LPFUN_LSAICRYPTUNPROTECTDATA pLsaICryptUnprotectData = (LPFUN_LSAICRYPTUNPROTECTDATA) GetProcAddress (hLsasrv, "LsaICryptUnprotectData");
    if(!pLsaICryptUnprotectData) 
    {return GetLastError();}

HANDLE credfile = NULL;
LPBYTE buffer = NULL;
LPBYTE pDecrypted = NULL;
DWORD dwSize = 0;
DWORD cbsize=0;

credfile = CreateFile(filename,GENERIC_READ,0,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN|FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM,NULL);   


dwSize = GetFileSize(credfile,NULL);    
buffer=(LPBYTE)malloc(dwSize);
SetFilePointer(credfile,0,0,FILE_BEGIN);
DWORD credFileSize=0;
ReadFile(credfile,buffer,dwSize,&credFileSize,NULL)

if(!pLsaICryptUnprotectData( buffer, dwSize, 0,0,0,0, 0, 0, &pDecrypted, &cbsize) != NULL))
{
// do error handling
}
```

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: @Johny I have added my test harness. basically right after the call pLsaICryptUnprotectData, I get error code 87 (parameter not supported)   bytes read (cbsize) is also 0.

Answer (score 0):

The `LsalCryptUnprotectData` function is undocumented, but from [this example](http://www.rsdn.ru/forum/cpp.applied/4815136.hot), you might try with similar parameters:

```
cbSize = 0;
pLsaICryptUnprotectData ( buffer, dwSize, 0,0,0,0, 0x20000041, 0, 
    &pDecrypted, &cbSize);
```

Comment: I was using exactly that! but i still get error code 87. do the buffer have to be malloc'ed before being passed in?

Comment: @Syler In the examples I've seen, the output buffer *is* allocated first. You can certainly try both ways, but make sure you're not misinterpreting the error - as the function is documented, you don't even know if it returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` when it succeeds. Do you get any data, even if `cbSize` is zero?